# Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression (SQLModel)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

I'm making a GraphQL api with strawberry using SQLModel as the database manager. I'm trying to get a list of items where a substring is in a string so I did this

```
def resolve_user(id: int):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        user = session.exec(
            select(UserModel).where(UserModel.id == id)
        ).one()

        return create_user_instance(user)

# I belive the error comes from here
def resolve_users_by_name(name: str):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        users = session.exec(
            select(UserModel).where(name in UserModel.name)
        ).all()

        return [create_user_instance(user) for user in users]


@strawberry.type
class Query:
    user: User = strawberry.field(resolver=resolve_user)
    users_by_name: list[User] = strawberry.field(
        resolver=resolve_users_by_name
    )
```

When calling the `usersByName` query I get the error `Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression`. I'm guessing it has to do with the `name in UserModel.name`. I also looked if SQLModel had a `LIKE` operator similar to SQL but I couldn't find anything. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The line that is having the issue is:

```
select(UserModel).where(name in UserModel.name)
```

Try changing it to this format:

```
select(UserModel).where(UserModel.name.contains(name))
```

[Sqlalchemy's comparator class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY.Comparator) has a set of methods you have to leverage, instead of vanilla python.

(I think [this is a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798893/sqlachemy-hybrid-property-error-operator-is-not-supported-on-this-expression))